# htaccess url shortening works locally not on server

Tags: .htaccess, url, friendly-url

I wonder if anyone can take a look at this htaccess and tell me why it should work on a localhost but not on server

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news(.*)$ news.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^view/([^/]+)/([^/]+).html /view.php?content_id=$1&content_id=$2 [NC]
```

Comment: What errors do you get on your server?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `RewriteBase /subdirectory` or rename it to `RewriteBase /`.